# CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an application in which I am using SQlite database. My application works good in each and every OS version and in all emulators but it only creates problem in device with **OS version 2.3.3**.  I am getting CREATE TABLE android_metadata messages and my database code crashes.

**I am Using Google Nexus with Android OS 2.3.3**

Please suggest me what is the actual problem and what I can do to solve this device dependent problem. I am also posting my code below.:

```
public class ECatalogueDatabase {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.weg.ecatalogue/databases/";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ECatalogue";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "T_Electrical";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="id";
    public static final String KEY_PRODUCT_LINE="productline";

    public static final String KEY_VOLTAGE="voltage";
    public static final String KEY_OUTPUTHP="outputhp";

    public static final String KEY_FRAME="frame";
    public static final String KEY_RPM="rpm";

    private Context context=null;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String CREAT_DATABASE="Create Table if not exists "+ DATABASE_TABLE+"("+ KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
    +KEY_PRODUCT_LINE +" nvarchar ,"+ KEY_OUTPUTHP+" numeric ,"+ KEY_RPM +" nvarchar ,"+KEY_VOLTAGE +" nvarchar ," +KEY_FRAME +" nvarchar"+")";

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     *
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public ECatalogueDatabase(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    //Helper class
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREAT_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public ECatalogueDatabase open() //throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();


        SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
        if(dbExist){
        //DO NOTHING IN THIS CASE
        }else{

        db_Read = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();
        }
        //=================================

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }

    }
    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        }

        if(db != null){

            db.close();

        }

        return db != null ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{


        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;


        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public int getDatabaseCount(){
        int count = 0;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        if(cursor!=null){
            count = cursor.getCount();
        }
        cursor.deactivate();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }

}
```

**My Logcates**:

```
5CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
a
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java1987)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java1855)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java820)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java854)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java847)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java567)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java203)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java118)
    at com.weg.ecatalogue.database.ECatalogueDatabase.open(ECatalogueDatabase.java76)
    at com.weg.ecatalogue.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java219)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java1722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java1784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$00(ActivityThread.java123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java3839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Deleting and re-creating corrupt database /data/data/com.weg.ecatalogus/ECatalogue
a
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java1987)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java1855)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java820)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java854)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java847)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java567)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java203)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java118)
    at com.weg.ecatalogue.database.ECatalogueDatabase.open(ECatalogueDatabase.java76)
    at com.weg.ecatalogue.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java219)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java1722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java1784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$00(ActivityThread.java123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java3839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please do not keep the error message a secret.

Comment: "my database code crashes" means nothing

Comment: I have attached my logcats and  apologies if i had not explained my problem well:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was totally different problem which I was getting only in few devices like HTC Nexus ONE device and it was working in all OS and all other devices.

When we create database we get a table generated automatically named "android_table", I deleted that table and recreated that manually in my SQLite manager. via below two steps of query:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

And after this step when I run the code, I got the surprise before Christmas. My application is working fine now.

All credit goes to my long R & D and this link which I got after so much efforts:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 1):

try using :

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(your_path, null, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```